# Identifying filling foods for cutting / fat loss

Tags: weight-loss, cutting

I'm looking into reducing calorie intake for cutting while maintaining the feeling of satiety. How can one identify foods that are filling?

NutritionData.Self.com has a useful ["Fullness factor"](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/soups-sauces-and-gravies/10066/2), but I don't see a way to sort by that.

[image]

Any ideas or other web sites that may provide this data?

Comment: Protein and vegetables normally do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't provide you with a sortable "fullness factor" database - here's exactly how I would get a list of the foods you're looking for...

First, you need a sortable list - and you can download the USDA nutrient database in excel here: http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=23634

You can begin with sorting all the foods ascending by calories - and you'll quickly realize you can chew through pound after pound of different vegetables & fruits every day (while easily staying well within your calorie limits).

Now, since fiber (http://jn.nutrition.org/content/130/2/272S.short) and proteins (http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07315724.2004.10719381#.VRSVZ_nF98M) have been proven to increase satiety...

You could also try sorting by fiber or protein columns or even make a calculated column, like fiber/calories or protein/calories and sort by those columns - to come up with a list of "highly-filling foods" (that only bring a few calories to the table).

Comment: oh, and the NutritionData "Fullness Factor" is probably calculated in some similar way too...at least I never heard of something like that being a part of official nutritional measurements

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that NutritionData does have a [search by fullness factor](http://nutritiondata.self.com/tools/nutritional-target-map-search):

[image: NutritionData fullness]

A [1995 study shows the satiety index of common foods](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/15701207_A_Satiety_Index_of_common_foods).

Fitness coach Jeremy Ethier has a video that talks about the satiety index and lists some foods [at 2:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7seSnZ1k1A&t=140s): popcorn, porridge, fish, potatoes, oranges & apples are more satiating than other foods.